# secondary upstream/backup GIT repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We currently use Atlassian Bitbucket (git) to store scripts we use to build and configure environments on our network.

Thinking in terms of DR, in a catastrophic event, we can rebuild our entire network using the scripts in Bitbucket.  But if our Bitbucket server died in the catastrophic event, I don't want step 1 of our recovery process to be "reconstitute the Bitbucket server from backups".

Is it possible to have an upstream repo, like GitHub, where code automatically pushed after it's checked into Bitbucket?

To be honest, I'm not sure if this is a Bitbucket thing or a Git thing.  I'm a sysadmin, not a developer.  So my experience with both is limited to rudimentary git operations with PyCharm, SourceTree, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but a short answer would be to keep your Git repositories (especially `.git` directories that contains all the objects and metadata) in your regular off-site backup which you can easily restore in case of an emergency.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But the key here is that I don't want to rely on a backup/restore process.  If I have to reconstitute our entire network,  I want a read-to-go offsite repo that matches the last checkins of our onsite repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for Bitbucket Data Center, you have a number of High Availability options. For offsite disaster recovery you can check out Atlassian's [Disaster recovery guide for Bitbucket Data Center](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/disaster-recovery-guide-for-bitbucket-data-center-833940586.html). This sort of setup would get you back to an operational state the most quickly, as other options (like auto-pushing to an alternative service) would mean a ton of workflow changes for your users - they would need to re-clone everything, change their remotes, and any metadata such as pull requests, comments, permissions etc would be lost. By setting up a disaster recovery instance as described above, in theory you could simply point your DNS record to the standby instance and your users could be up and running immediately.

Full disclosure: I'm a support engineer at Atlassian